# Anchor tests not passing unless I switch off Internet connection

Tags: anchor, tests, bug

Been struggling with this issue for a few days and can't figure it out.

I'll be brief.
My Anchor tests are not passing, but they are passing for everyone else who's running them.
For me, they fail in the connection part. Some errors I'm getting are:

- Transactions not being sent / not being confirmed
- "Invalid account data for instruction"
- Other errors that happen from there onwards (i.e. not enough balance due to a mint not getting executed and such)

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2, `solana-cli 1.9.29` and `anchor-cli 0.25.0`, exactly the same configuration as that of another computer where the tests are running all fine.

Now here is the crazy part: **if I switch off WiFi Internet connection, then the tests pass perfectly**. Note that my cluster is correctly configured as `localhost`/`localnet` both in the Solana CLI and `Anchor.toml` file of the project.
I reinstalled WSL and everything, and the issue persists.

What is going on here? How can this be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the ports used by `solana-test-validator` (8899, 8900) somehow used in your LAN? Any port forwards in your router for these ports?

Comment: They aren't. Also, I should mention that when connecting back to Internet, the tests pass (for a few times, until they don't anymore, or start to fail and pass non-deterministically)

Comment: almost sounds like there's some weird WSL networking config that's forwarding your guest localhost to the host's internet connection (when available). i'd suggest finding a WSL specific forum to ask in as this doesn't seem to be related to solana or anchor.

Comment: I noticed something else, I'll just add it here to see if it helps in any way. If I change the provider setting line from `const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();` to `const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.local(undefined, {commitment: 'confirmed',preflightCommitment: 'confirmed',});` then these tests work fine. Notice that the only difference is the confirm options, since I checked and env() is also localhost. Any clue?